# Solution of differential equation in Trigonometric functions of $x$ and $y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $$\frac{dy}{dx} +\frac{\cos x(3\cos y-7\sin x-3)}{\sin y(3\sin x-7\cos y+7)}=0$$

Attempt: $(3\sin x\sin y-7\cos y \sin y+7\sin y)dy+(3\cos x\cos y-7\sin x\cos -3\cos x)dx =0$

could some help me how to solve it , thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\dfrac{\sin y}{\cos x}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{d(\cos y)}{d(\sin x)}=-\dfrac{3\cos y-7\sin x-3}{3\sin x-7\cos y+7}$$ Now use a suitable variable transformation to get [a familiar equation](http://www.tau.ac.il/~levant/ode/solution_4.pdf) as in example 4.14.

Comment: See example 4.14 in the linked note.

Comment: Notice that comments are volatile. Please include all relevant stuff in the post itself. Thanks.

Comment: I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSC3g.png) . Isn't it an useful information that should be included in the post too?

Answer (score 1):

## Hint

Let $a=\sin x$ and $b=\sin y$, then substitute it in the original equation. For $\cos x$ use $\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}$ and similarly for $b$.